# draw circle in the end of SVG path in realtime line chart D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts

I need to draw circle in the end of SVG path in realtime line chart. I use d3.js for drawing chart. Everything is all right but this trouble confused me.

Please, tell me what is wrong in my code and help me to find better solution.

Thanks!

JS code:

```
var GraphIndex = (function() {
        var n = 10,
            duration = 15000,
            now = new Date(Date.now() - duration),
            random = d3.random.normal(0, 100),
            data = d3.range(n).map(random);

        var width = 379,
            height = 138;

        // X axis
        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration])
            .range([0, width - 40]);

        // Y axis
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([(-1)*d3.max(data) - 100, d3.max(data) + 100])
            .range([height, 0]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
           .interpolate("linear")
           .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
           .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

        var svg = d3.select(".graph-holder").append("svg")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height + 30);

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
           .attr("id", "clip")
         .append("rect")
           .attr("width", width - 40)
           .attr("height", height);

        // X Axis
        var axis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.minutes, 1));

        // Line
        var path = svg.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
            .attr("class", "path-area")
          .append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("id", "myPath");

        //Draw the Circle
        var circle = d3.select(".path-area")
            .append("svg:circle")
                .attr("cx", 335)
                .attr("cy", y(data[n - 2]))
                .attr("r", 4)
                .attr("class", "circle");

        this.tick = (function(){
            now = new Date();

            x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
            y.domain([(-1)*d3.max(data) - 100, d3.max(data) + 100]);

            var d = random()
            data.push(d);

            // redraw the line
            svg.select(".line")
                .attr("d", line)
                .attr("transform", null);

            // slide the x-axis left
            axis.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .ease("linear")
                .call(x.axis);

            // slide the line left
            path.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .ease("linear")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")")
                .each("end", tick);

             circle.transition()
                   .duration(duration)
                   .ease("linear")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + y(d) + ")");

            // pop the old data point off the front
            data.shift();
        });

        this.tick();
    });

    GraphIndex();
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="graph-holder"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
.graph-holder {
position: relative;
width: 379px; height: 138px;
}
.x-axis line {
  shape-rendering: auto;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.x-axis path,
.x-axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x-axis .tick {
    color: #fff;
    stroke: #fff;
    font-size: .75em;
}
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
circle {
    fill: #fff;
}
```

Comment: for more info see http://postimg.org/image/r3avgsw1x/ .


it looks like cardiogram

Comment: Instead of appending a `<circle>` geometry, could you instead use an SVG marker to draw a circle at the end of your path?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but i need use `<circle>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adjusting the `cy` of the circle rather than translating it? Your Y axis is not chaining so no need to transform the coord system.

So instead of

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0, " + y(d) + ")");
```

try

```
.attr("cy",  function() { return y(data[data.length-2]); });
```